# I am passing two query result inside view but only one result work.please give me a solution

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am passing two result inside view but only one result is working.

```
public function editCustomer(){

    $custId = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $desResult['designation'] = $this->ecd->hrmDesignationId();

    $result['editDetails'] = $this->ecd->editDetails($custId);
    $this->load->view('editCustomerDetails',$result,$desResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `$this->load->view()` method should be an array.

The proper way to do this is to build your array before calling the load method:

```
$result['designation'] = $this->ecd->hrmDesignationId();
$result['editDetails'] = $this->ecd->editDetails($custId);
$this->load->view('editCustomerDetails',$result);
```

The two variables will then be available in your view. You can write them down to check :

```
var_dump($designation);
var_dump($editDetails);
```